# Ambiguity in proof of angle of minimum deviation of for a prism

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics

I have stumbled upon a proof from one of my friends that for a prism, the angle of minimum deviation is that in which incident angle is equal to emergent angle. i.e.
$$\delta = i + e - A$$
where $A$ = Refracting angle of prism
The proof goes like this:
Since we have to minimize $i + e$, we can do so by using the AM-GM inequality
i.e.
$$\frac{i+e}{2} \geq \sqrt{ie}$$
This means that minimum value of $i+e$ is when the AM is equal to GM, i.e.
$$\frac{i+e}{2} = \sqrt{ie}$$
$$\implies i+e = 2\sqrt{ie}$$
$$ \implies (\sqrt{i} - \sqrt{e})^2 = 0 $$
$$\implies i = e$$

So is this proof valid??

I was thinking in general terms that since $e$ is a function of $i$, is it true for every function?
for example: if we define functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that both are always positive. So, does the minimum value of $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ occurs when $f(x) = g(x)$.
I have also found a counterexample to it:
assume $f(x) = x^2 - 6x + 10$ and $g(x) = x^2 - 5x + 7$.
Then $h(x) = 2x^2 - 11x + 17$, whose minimum value occurs at $x=11/4$, but by the AM-GM inequality method, it should occur when $f(x) = g(x)$ i.e. $x^2 -6x+10 = x^2 - 5x + 7$ i.e. minima occurs at $x = 3$, which is not correct.
So what actually went wrong here? So does this implies that the proof of angle of minimum deviation is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

You mixing up several things. On one hand AGI is true by the square completion:
$$
i+e\geq 2\sqrt{ie}
$$
with equality iff $i=e$. Similarly, $\delta$ reaches its minimum iff $i=e$. However, it is not because they reach the minimum at the same point that one proves the other. However, it turns out that there is a general argument that applies to both cases to find the minimum.

The key argument is that you want to minimize $i+e$ where one is obtained from the other by an involutive function:
$$
i=f(e)\\
e=f(i)
$$
In the case of AGI, $f$ is the inverse function which is involutive. In optics, $f$ is complicated, but you know that it is involutive by reversing the direction of the light ray (time reversibility).

Looking at the stationary point of the sum, depending on whether you vary $i$ or $e$, yoi find:
$$
f’(i)=f’(e)=-1
$$
so inverting $f’$:
$$
i=e
$$
Usually, $f$ is often convex (including the optical case), so the minimisation problem is well posed. Also, this justifies the search of critical points and the inversion of $f’$ which will be increasing.

Hope this helps.